# how to extract exact strings from str_extract?

Tags: r, stringr

I have the a text vector called `eventext` and I want to extract values from this vector that have `"PR"` in it. However, when I used this on my real data, I realized that I am also picking up values like `"PRESENT"` because the word contains `"PR"` in it.

```
  library(stringr)
    eventtext<-c("PRESENT","PR-BOND","PR","No BOND")
    str_extract(eventtext,"PR")
```

Current output is

```
"PR" "PR" "PR" NA
```

What I would want is

```
NA "PR" "PR" NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use word boundary so that it won't match the characters inside a word

```
str_extract(eventtext, "\\bPR\\b")
#[1] NA   "PR" "PR" NA
```